# Something goes wrong with Hilt dependency

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, dagger-hilt

there are 2 errors when i try to build my app:

1. [Hilt]
2. 

Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'.

> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptWithoutKotlincTask$KaptExecutionWorkAction> java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException (no error message)```

How to fix it? I'm pretty sure that declared all the dependency about hilt for my project:

Here is my dependency:

```
dependencies
 {  
  
implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.10.1")  
implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.6.1")  
implementation("androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.7.0")  
implementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.08.00"))  
implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui")  
implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-graphics")  
implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview")  
implementation("androidx.compose.material3:material3")  
testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")  
androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")  
androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")  
androidTestImplementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.08.00"))  
androidTestImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4")  
debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling")  
debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest")

val nav_version = "2.7.7"  
// Kotlin  
implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$nav_version")  
implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$nav_version")  
// Jetpack Compose Integration  
implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:$nav_version")

val room_version = "2.6.1"  
implementation("androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version")  
annotationProcessor("androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version")  
// To use Kotlin annotation processing tool (kapt)  
kapt("androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version")  
// optional - Kotlin Extensions and Coroutines support for Room  
implementation("androidx.room:room-ktx:$room_version")

// hilt  
implementation("com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.48")  
kapt("com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.44")  
implementation("androidx.hilt:hilt-lifecycle-viewmodel:1.0.0-alpha03")  
kapt ("androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.1.0")

//hilt+navigation  
implementation*("androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-compose:1.1.0")

}

plugins {
id("com.android.application")  
id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")  
id("com.google.dagger.hilt.android")  
id ("kotlin-kapt")
}
```

In the Gradle(Project file):

```
plugins {
id("com.android.application") version "8.2.2" apply false  
id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android") version "1.9.0" apply false  
id("com.google.dagger.hilt.android") version "2.44" apply false
}
```

Comment: please share a complete error code. you can checkout from logcat.

Comment: It would be nice if you create gist for reproducing the issue or you can refer this solution as most of hilt issues occur due to compatibility issues or wrong implementation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77782613/cannot-implement-hilt-with-compose-activity/77825644

Comment: I also encounter an issue with the most recent version Android Studio Iguana and Hilt. Reverting to Hedgehog version, it works again now. The build error message from Hilt was: "Type mismatch: inferred type is Any! but ClassLoader was expected".

Answer (score 0):

change dependency version of hilt.
with `ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.0'`

```
androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0
```

u can use this one

```
implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.45"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.45"
```

and classpath

```
classpath "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:2.45"
```

Comment: It doesn't work at all.

Comment: Then see your implementtion issue must be ocurred from there,

Answer (score 0):

**Well, when i changed "kapt" to "annotationProcessor" and then built, it worked. But I have run the app after, the app keeps crashing and shows these errors: ( I have one thing that makes me confused. I'm creating a note with jetpack compose + kotlin. I has to be kapt for kotlin and annotationProcessor for java. I saw on the document .)**

*Errors:*

```
2024-02-23 21:07:02.121 14555-14555 ziparchive              com...mple.noteappcleanarchitecture  W  Unable to open '/data/app/~~u4sbbJ2rlJCY7WfA4M73Uw==/com.example.noteappcleanarchitecture-uaWcJWnMfun7jbYCedFSNA==/base.dm': No such file or directory
2024-02-23 21:07:02.121 14555-14555 ziparchive              com...mple.noteappcleanarchitecture  W  Unable to open '/data/app/~~u4sbbJ2rlJCY7WfA4M73Uw==/com.example.noteappcleanarchitecture-uaWcJWnMfun7jbYCedFSNA==/base.dm': No such file or directory
2024-02-23 21:07:02.289 14555-14555 nativeloader            com...mple.noteappcleanarchitecture  D  Configuring clns-6 for other apk /data/app/~~u4sbbJ2rlJCY7WfA4M73Uw==/com.example.noteappcleanarchitecture-uaWcJWnMfun7jbYCedFSNA==/base.apk. target_sdk_version=34, uses_libraries=, library_path=/data/app/~~u4sbbJ2rlJCY7WfA4M73Uw==/com.example.noteappcleanarchitecture-uaWcJWnMfun7jbYCedFSNA==/lib/x86_64, permitted_path=/data:/mnt/expand:/data/user/0/com.example.noteappcleanarchitecture
2024-02-23 21:07:02.299 14555-14555 GraphicsEnvironment     com...mple.noteappcleanarchitecture  V  Currently set values for:
2024-02-23 21:07:02.299 14555-14555 GraphicsEnvironment     com...mple.noteappcleanarchitecture  V    angle_gl_driver_selection_pkgs=[]
2024-02-23 21:07:02.299 14555-14555 GraphicsEnvironment     com...mple.noteappcleanarchitecture  V    angle_gl_driver_selection_values=[]
2024-02-23 21:07:02.300 14555-14555 GraphicsEnvironment     com...mple.noteappcleanarchitecture  V  ANGLE GameManagerService for com.example.noteappcleanarchitecture: false
2024-02-23 21:07:02.300 14555-14555 GraphicsEnvironment     com...mple.noteappcleanarchitecture  V  com.example.noteappcleanarchitecture is not listed in per-application setting
2024-02-23 21:07:02.300 14555-14555 GraphicsEnvironment     com...mple.noteappcleanarchitecture  V  Neither updatable production driver nor prerelease driver is supported.
2024-02-23 21:07:02.305 14555-14555 AndroidRuntime          com...mple.noteappcleanarchitecture  D  Shutting down VM
2024-02-23 21:07:02.310 14555-14555 AndroidRuntime          com...mple.noteappcleanarchitecture  E  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                                    Process: com.example.noteappcleanarchitecture, PID: 14555
                                                                                                   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.example.noteappcleanarchitecture.NoteApp package com.example.noteappcleanarchitecture: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.noteappcleanarchitecture.NoteApp" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~u4sbbJ2rlJCY7WfA4M73Uw==/com.example.noteappcleanarchitecture-uaWcJWnMfun7jbYCedFSNA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~u4sbbJ2rlJCY7WfA4M73Uw==/com.example.noteappcleanarchitecture-uaWcJWnMfun7jbYCedFSNA==/lib/x86_64, /system/lib64, /system_ext/lib64]]
                                                                                                        at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplicationInner(LoadedApk.java:1466)
                                                                                                        at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplicationInner(LoadedApk.java:1395)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6959)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.-$$Nest$mhandleBindApplication(Unknown Source:0)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2236)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:205)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:294)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8177)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:552)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:971)
                                                                                                    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.noteappcleanarchitecture.NoteApp" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~u4sbbJ2rlJCY7WfA4M73Uw==/com.example.noteappcleanarchitecture-uaWcJWnMfun7jbYCedFSNA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~u4sbbJ2rlJCY7WfA4M73Uw==/com.example.noteappcleanarchitecture-uaWcJWnMfun7jbYCedFSNA==/lib/x86_64, /system/lib64, /system_ext/lib64]]
                                                                                                        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:259)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
                                                                                                        at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateApplication(AppComponentFactory.java:76)
                                                                                                        at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateApplication(CoreComponentFactory.java:52)
                                                                                                        at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:1282)
                                                                                                        at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplicationInner(LoadedApk.java:1458)
                                                                                                        at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplicationInner(LoadedApk.java:1395) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6959) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.-$$Nest$mhandleBindApplication(Unknown Source:0) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2236) 
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:205) 
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:294) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8177) 
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:552) 
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:971) 
                                                                                                        Suppressed: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/example/noteappcleanarchitecture/Hilt_NoteApp;
                                                                                                            at java.lang.VMClassLoader.findLoadedClass(Native Method)
                                                                                                            at java.lang.ClassLoader.findLoadedClass(ClassLoader.java:738)
                                                                                                            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:363)
                                                                                                            ... 16 more
                                                                                                        Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.noteappcleanarchitecture.Hilt_NoteApp" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~u4sbbJ2rlJCY7WfA4M73Uw==/com.example.noteappcleanarchitecture-uaWcJWnMfun7jbYCedFSNA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~u4sbbJ2rlJCY7WfA4M73Uw==/com.example.noteappcleanarchitecture-uaWcJWnMfun7jbYCedFSNA==/lib/x86_64, /system/lib64, /system_ext/lib64]]
                                                                                                            at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:259)
                                                                                                            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
                                                                                                            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
                                                                                                            ... 19 more
```

Comment: I have added NoteApp Application in AndroidManifest (<application
        android:name=".NoteApp"),. So why didn't find it?

Comment: You need use ```2.48.1``` Hilt Version.

Comment: why? sir. I read the document on android developer page. it said 2.44

Comment: I was facing issue while using ```2.44``` And when moved to ```2.48.1``` it worked best for me

Comment: Are u using android hedgehog?

Comment: Please, I want to know your android studio's version and both gradle and sdk version.

Comment: I'm using android studio Iguana RC2 and gradle 8.2.2 and SDK version 34